# Nginx configuration issue: Cannot GET /index.html while deploying frontend and backend on AWS EC2

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

I'm encountering an error when trying to deploy both the frontend and backend of my application on AWS EC2 using Nginx. I have set up Nginx to serve both the backend and frontend, but I'm receiving a `404 Not Found` error with the message "Cannot GET /index.html" when trying to access the frontend.

Here's my Nginx configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`):

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name localhost;

 location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }

 root /var/www/admin;

 location /admin-panel {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
 }
}
```

I expect that when accessing `http://<my-ec2-instance-ip>/admin-panel`, it should serve the index.html file located at /var/www/admin/index.html. However, I'm receiving a 404 error instead.

Could someone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!